# Use logs severity with Google Compute Engine and the Cloud Logging agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I'd like to use logs severity with the [Google Cloud Logging agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs) and a linux (Debian) VM running on Compute Engine.

The Compute Engine instance is a debian-9 n2-standard-4 machine.

I've installed the Cloud Logging agent by following [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation).

```
$ curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/add-logging-agent-repo.sh
$ sudo bash add-logging-agent-repo.sh
$ sudo apt-get install google-fluentd
$ sudo apt-get install -y google-fluentd-catch-all-config-structured
$ sudo service google-fluentd start
```

And according to [this paragraph](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#special-fields), we can use log severity if the log line is a serialized JSON object and if the option detect_json is set to true.

So I log something like below, but unfortunately I don't have any severity in GCP.

```
$ logger '{"severity":"ERROR","message":"This is an error"}'
```

[image]

But I would expect something like this:

[image]

I don't mind the type of the log entry being textPayload or jsonPayload.

The file `/etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf` with detect_json enable:

```
$ cat /etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf 
# Master configuration file for google-fluentd

# Include any configuration files in the config.d directory.
#
# An example "catch-all" configuration can be found at
# https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/fluentd-catch-all-config
@include config.d/*.conf

# Prometheus monitoring.
<source>
  @type prometheus
  port 24231
</source>
<source>
  @type prometheus_monitor
</source>

# Do not collect fluentd's own logs to avoid infinite loops.
<match fluent.**>
  @type null
</match>

# Add a unique insertId to each log entry that doesn't already have it.
# This helps guarantee the order and prevent log duplication.
<filter **>
  @type add_insert_ids
</filter>

# Configure all sources to output to Google Cloud Logging
<match **>
  @type google_cloud
  buffer_type file
  buffer_path /var/log/google-fluentd/buffers
  # Set the chunk limit conservatively to avoid exceeding the recommended
  # chunk size of 5MB per write request.
  buffer_chunk_limit 512KB
  # Flush logs every 5 seconds, even if the buffer is not full.
  flush_interval 5s
  # Enforce some limit on the number of retries.
  disable_retry_limit false
  # After 3 retries, a given chunk will be discarded.
  retry_limit 3
  # Wait 10 seconds before the first retry. The wait interval will be doubled on
  # each following retry (20s, 40s...) until it hits the retry limit.
  retry_wait 10
  # Never wait longer than 5 minutes between retries. If the wait interval
  # reaches this limit, the exponentiation stops.
  # Given the default config, this limit should never be reached, but if
  # retry_limit and retry_wait are customized, this limit might take effect.
  max_retry_wait 300
  # Use multiple threads for processing.
  num_threads 8
  # Use the gRPC transport.
  use_grpc true
  # If a request is a mix of valid log entries and invalid ones, ingest the
  # valid ones and drop the invalid ones instead of dropping everything.
  partial_success true
  # Enable monitoring via Prometheus integration.
  enable_monitoring true
  monitoring_type opencensus
  detect_json true
</match>
```

The file `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf
<source>
  @type tail

  # Parse the timestamp, but still collect the entire line as 'message'
  format syslog

  path /var/log/syslog
  pos_file /var/lib/google-fluentd/pos/syslog.pos
  read_from_head true
  tag syslog
</source>
```

What am I missing ?

Note: I am aware of the [glcoud workaround](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/tools/gcloud-logging#write_entry), but it is not ideal since it logs everything under the resource type 'Global', not in my VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logger uses syslog, and syslog "parse the timestamp, but still collect the entire line as 'message' "

as described in  ***/etc/google-fluentd/config.d/syslog.conf***

In your case, you can use log severity by [streaming structured logs via structured-log files](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/configuration#structured-records) with json format.

Here is the result of

**echo '{"severity":"ERROR","message":"This is an error"}' >> /tmp/test-structured-log.log**

[image]